# Problems with my css stylesheet coding

Tags: css

I have a similar problem like others have had, but the answers did not help.

This is my coding:

```
        <div id="social-media">
            <p>for aditional information<br>please call 03-5185-1208<p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                   <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                        <img src="images/social media/facebook 32x32.png">
                   </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
                      <img src="images/social media/twitter 32x32.png">
                    </a>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

My css style sheet

```
ul li{ display:inline; text-decoration:none; }
```

but the underline still remain. I have tried everything included

```
{  border-bottom:none;  }
```

Nothing did work. Can anyone help please?

Comment: The underline might be on the `a` tag, try targeting that

Comment: @jedifans fairly certain you're correct. `li` doesn't have an implicit underline but `a` does.

Comment: Good job fixing all the code blocks, reporter.

Comment: yes thank you so much it was the a tag, im just learning i think ive spent to much time on the computer i need a break thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Use like this

```
ul li{ display:inline;  }
ul li a{text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
ul li a{ display:inline; text-decoration:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ul li a{ display:inline; text-decoration:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> check this, it works fine

```css
ul li{ display:inline; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:none;}
a{text-decoration:none}
```

```html
<div id="social-media">
            <p>for aditional information<br>please call 03-5185-1208<p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                   <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                        <img width="40px" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-icons-the-circle-set/48/facebook_circle-128.png">
                   </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
                      <img width="40px" src="http://cipm.kau.edu.sa/images/714/twitter1.png">
                    </a>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```